# upstream timeout while reading response header from upstream client 172.17.0.1

Tags: python, docker, flask

```
upstream timeout while reading response header from upstream client 172.17.0.1...
```

Getting this error while running a docker image not sure why this error is coming. I tried running the same image on a different computer and it is working fine.

The docker command I used to run this program:

```
docker run -e "PORT=8765" -p 8007:8765 akash9179/flask-vue
```

The full error:

```
10#10: *2 upstream timed out (110: operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client:172.17.0.1, server: request: "GET /users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/users", host: "localhost:8007", referrer: "http://localhost:8007/".
```

The Dockerfile ends with:

```
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app --daemon && \
      sed -i -e 's/$PORT/'"$PORT"'/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
      nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Comment: This question is missing a few things: (1) Any code/error should be included in the question body, not as an attached image. (2) Please include the docker run command you use to launch this. (3) Possibly add the Dockerfile so we know what you're trying to run.  Also see: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You should edit your question if you wish for good answers :-)

Comment: I have edited the question and included the docker run command which I used and the full error.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you add the `Dockerfile` also, or a link to the repo.  I can't find `akash9179/flask-vue` on dockerhub so I'm guessing it's from a private registry.

Comment: The repository is public here is the link : https://hub.docker.com/r/akash9179/flask-vue

Comment: you can also check on github : https://github.com/Akash9179/flaskvue

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the way you're invoking the servers in the Dockerfile:

```
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app --daemon && \
      sed -i -e 's/$PORT/'"$PORT"'/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
      nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

I suspect with this `CMD` line, nginx doesn't actually run until the `gunicorn` process sucessfully completes, which as it's running a server it won't.

The correct way to architect this is to have a separate Dockerfile for both the gunicorn server and the nginx server. You're trying to pack too much into a single Dockerfile. **Each container should run one process!**

You should then define these as separate services in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-flask
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
```

Within each container the service name (that's `flask` and `nginx`) can be used to access the other container in place of a hostname. So in the nginx config, where you do the `proxy_pass` lines, you could have something like:

```
  location /ping {
    proxy_pass      http://flask:5000;
  }
```

Also there's probably no point in that `sed` line which overwrites the `default.conf` to change the nginx port number. I would stick with a static nginx port in the config, and then when you do the run command, just have it documented a user knows they need to map their own preferred external port, to that of your nginx server.

This also would avoid the need to pass in PORT as an environment variable.